Could not access Laravel API routes
Since I was learning next.js, I also start learning laravel API. I generally used laravel with livewire and stuff and never touch API. I started reading the docs and follow the instructions.
I install the API (sanctum) using this command provided by laravel:
php artisan install:api

Then I created a simple login
public function store(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Invalid Credentials',
        ], 401);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => Auth::user()->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken,
    ]);
}

And define my routes
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatedSessionController;

Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

Now, I started the local server and access the API using postman. I'm expecting a 419 error when I access the login page since I'm not accessing the csrf route. But I get a 404 not found error. Then I tried access the route define by laravel which is user and it return 404 too. So I run php artisan optimize:clear and still the error persist. Also after installing the api I removed the web routes, so I thought maybe it is required, so define the web routes again and clear the routes but still the error is there. So I tried defining a routes in web and that works. But based on the docs it should start working after we install the api. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?
EDIT: I tried creating a new test project and just install the api add a test route and encounter the same error. I also tried doing a feature test which result with same error.
EDIT2: This what my route list looks like


I think your issue may be on the webserver, what are you using locally to serve this?

I used xampp and I also have a modified vhost. I'm not sure if that would affect the laravel app since laravel start it's own server right?

@SpamBug, Are you sure that you have registered api.php in boostrap/app.php file properly and your API access endpoint is correct?

Yes, also running php artisan install:api should automatically register the api.php. It also define a user route but that route also doesn't work.

Try running php artisan route:list. It will show you if the routes exists and their proper url. Maybe you forgot to add /api before the /login. If the route is defined inside the api.php you need to add /api before the actual defined url.

@SpamBug, there might be some issue with apache.

Have you correctly seted the APP_URL on the prod server? Run php artisan optimize on the prod server (not locally)

I started using laravel sail and installing the api simply works. So it seems my local development setup had to do something about this issue.
